# hibernate sorting

Tags: hibernate, sorting

hey i want to do nested sorting in hibernate.

i have a set of `application`s in `course` object. `application` has a `time` and `type` attribute.
I want to sort by `type` first and then within application of particular type i want to sort it by `time`.

can i use it as follows??

```
order-by="type desc,time asc"
```

Note that type should be sorted descendingly ( type is a int datatype in java)
and time ascendingly (time is of date datatype in jave )

eg of ordering  
 Type   time 
                  5           1 
                  5        2 
                  5         3
                  4         1
                   4         2

time was given as integer in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort just like you said.  You may also want to add the comparable interface to your objects so you can sort them in your services.

The following hibernate file has an example of using an sql bit for sorting

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="au.gov.abs.maserati.domain.entity.CURF" 
        table="CURF" >
        <id name="ID" column="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="title" />
        <property name="description" />
        <property name="active"
            type="yes_no" 
            not-null="true" />

        <set name="specialConditions" cascade="none"
            order-by="sortOrder, Text1"
            where=" Discriminator in ( 'SPECIAL-CURF-AGREEMENT' ) and active = 'Y' ">
            <key column="parentID" not-null="false" />
            <one-to-many
                class="au.gov.abs.maserati.domain.entity.Condition" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```